# Odd Error in ColdFusion App

Tags: session, coldfusion

Help - I am at my wits end...

I have a user that is experiencing a very odd response to my ColdFusion app. I have some session vars that control the contents of a drop-down. For some reason, her session vars do not go away when the session ends. When she gets to the screen with the drop-down, it has a value from a previous session selected and an item that has been removed from the database is in the drop-down.

I have tried the following: had her clear cookies and cache, had her get out of the browser entirely, had her reboot her machine, had her sign on from home,  had her run a virus check, had her do SHIFT+F5 on the page. I even logged on to her machine as me (and had no issues). We turned debug on for her machine, and I have a printout of the session vars - which do NOT have the same values as she sees when she gets to that page.

When I run the query that creates the data for that drop-down in the database directly, I don't get the item that was deleted. When I run the app, everything looks normal.

I have around 40 other users of this app that are not experiencing this issue.

What else can I try?

adding code for Dan

This is the filtered select:

```
<cfquery dbtype="query" name="qGetERs"> 
SELECT distinct * 
FROM qGetERs 
WHERE upper(er_id) like upper('#session.erfilterval#') 
ORDER By created_date DESC, er_log_number >
```

this loads into

```
<cfselect name="er_log_number" 
    size="1" query="qGetERs" 
    value="er_number" 
    display="ER_ID"   
    selected="#session.er_number#" >
</cfselect>
```

These two session vars are stuck at prior values...

this is above the query and url values are passed via a form GET

```
 <cfif not isDefined('session.erFilterval')>
    <cfset session.erFilterval = '%'>
 </cfif>
 <cfif isDefined('url.filter')>
     <cfset session.erfilter = url.filter>
     <cfset session.erfilterval = "%" & url.filter & "%">
 </cfif>
```

this happens when a value is selected in the list via a form GET:

```
 <cfif isDefined('url.seq_request_key')>
       <cfset qGetER = er.getER(#url.seq_request_key#)>
       <cfset session.er_number = qGetER.er_log_number & " - " & qGetER.revision>
       <cfset session.er_log_number = qGetER.er_log_number>
       <cfset session.revision = qGetER.revision>
 </cfif>
```

Why would just this one person have a problem with this code? It has been running for several months and with 40 something users banging away at it daily.

Comment: Show us the code that sets these two session variables as well. The problem won't be where the variable is read but where (how--conditions etc) the variable is set.

Comment: For the user having the problem, what is it that happens that makes one think that her session has ended?

Comment: Thank you for coming back and updating your question as requested. How are these url parameters passed? Via links? Via traditional form-gets? Via AJAX requests? Lastly, the query you provided is a Query-of-Query, can you provide the original query as well? I'm scratching my head as well. I would say the sessions simply are not being set but you insist that they are being set but for some reason not being carried over to this page.

Comment: I would add this to your onRequestEnd `<cftry><cfif SESSION.USER_IDENTIFIER is "THE PROBLEM USERNAME OR USERID"><cffile action="append" file="#expandpath("/")#debugging.html" output="#cgi.script_name#:<br>#SerializeJson(session)#<br><br>"></cfif><cfcatch><!-- debugwrite error occurred --></cfcatch></cftry>` and watch what happens when you get to each page, particularly the pages where they should be set, and the page where they should be read. Make sure to edit the cfif to list some identifier pertinent to the user ([user is "suziproblems"] or maybe [userid eq 666])

Comment: Of course, debugging files should be in a secure folder, outside of the webroot.

Comment: If this was my problem, I would sit down with the person and quietly, repeat quietly, watch her work.  Take notes.  Of particular importance is the action that you expect to end the session.  Then go back to your desk and do what she did.

Comment: If I understand you, this person logged in from 2 different computers and had the same problem right? So the issue is with this _login_, not with the browser or (probably) session handling. I would figure out what is different about this login. What cookies are being set that are not (for example) being set by _your_ login.

Comment: @DanBracuk - I have her get out of her browser to end the session.

Comment: @cfqueryparam - the urls are passed via traditional form-gets.

Comment: @cfqueryparam - original query is just a straight select of all records that match her id from a cfc call...which when I run it in the back-end, does NOT get the deleted item

Comment: @MarkAKruger - not two different computers, two different connections to our intranet. She took her computer home with her. I still think it is something with her computer or how she gets to the app.

Comment: @Casuzen - ok, has she tried a different browser on the same computer?

Comment: @MarkAKruger - unfortunately, as a user, the company restricts her to just IE..

Comment: When I get into the office, I am going to check the bookmark she uses to get to the app. I am wondering if the fragments of leftovers are from a browser session that should have expired long ago, but she keeps returning it to life by what is in her bookmark.

Comment: @Casuzen, `took her computer home` is a different thing than `tried from home. Bookmarks is a good culprit, as well as homepage, etc. Good luck, and make sure to let us know.

Comment: I'm going to guess some kind of plugin is saving username/pass and autologgin for her - or as you suggest she's going there with a bookmark that is resulting in a reset of the session to previous values. If so that would be a bug I think - it would allow a link to be emailed around and arbitrary people loggin in - wouldn't it?

Comment: @MarkAKruger - thought of that is pretty scary, eh?

Comment: Sigh...its not her bookmark.

Comment: @cfqueryparam - she did try from home, with the same results. I am going to have her sign onto a different machine and see if that has the same issue.

Comment: good call.. if it's the machine I'd scan the heck out of it :)

Comment: Actually...it WAS related to her bookmark. We had her get rid of the bookmark and go back in the long way and re-bookmark it once she got in right. Now..I STILL want to know WHERE the machine was hiding those url and session vars...but at least the user is back in business.

Comment: She was able to make the 'mystery' fields show back up again if she changes the url to use the 'friendly' name for the machine...using the machine's name real name seems to work.

Comment: There is a very stupid setting in IE...to NEVER clear cache...once that was set to something different, the user logged out and logged back in and et voila' - no more issue. Probably will never find who set that to Never...but I would like to...and give them a piece of my mind!!